# Using tExtractJsonNode to extract two nested fields from json in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

In Talend, I read from MongoDB objects with the following shape:

```
{ "field1" : "blah",
  "field2" : 
             "{ "field22" : "bloh", 
              "field23": "cc"} " 
}
```

So they get transformed in rows with two columns: field1 and field2.

Now I would like to transform that json into a row of three field: field1, field22 and field23. So I take my row and I attach to it a tExtractJsonNode, which gives me a row with field22 and field23. How do I merge that newly generated row with my initial row containing field1 too?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to specify any JsonQuery in the tExtractJsonNode for those fields who needs to be forwarded "as is"